# How to add a row to a txt file at the end for calculations?

Tags: python, r, sql-server

I have a text file that's generated from SSIS and the data is from a SQL Server database. There are no column headers in the text file. In the text file, I am needing to see if there is a way for me to add a row to the very bottom of the first column only that does some calculations(count and sum).

For example, current text file is like this:

```
111 Test Street         Texas                John Doe         20.00
123 Test Street         Alabama              John Doe         30.00
```

I am looking to see if I can get it to look like this where it counts the total records as well as add the last column:

```
111 Test Street         Texas                John Doe         20.00
123 Test Street         Alabama              John Doe         30.00
Users: 2   Amount: 50.00
```

Comment: do you want to do this in SSIS or R? If R, are trying to create a text file with the added row?

Comment: Either is fine, I'm just not familiar with how to do this in either one whether it be SSIS, R, or Python. Basically the txt file that exports via SSIS, I need to have this calculation row added to the end. So if this involves taking the exported txt file and then recreating it again with the row at the bottom, that would work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple way in R with `iris` as example dummy data. Let me know if this meets your needs -

```
# read your data into a dataframe
df <- iris[1:2, ]
# create this file in your working directory
sink(file = "test.txt", type = "output")
# add dataframe as is to text file
df
# add summary line to data frame
cat(
  paste0("Users: ", unique(df$Species), "     Total: ", sum(df$Sepal.Length)),
  file = 'test.txt', append = T, sep = '\n'
  )
# close connection to text file
sink()

# output text file -

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
Users: setosa     Total: 10
```

Comment: This may work, I will give it a try with my data. In the text file afterwards though, will it show the [1] in front of the summary line?

Comment: Yes, it will show [1]. You may need a different approach if you want precise formatting. Let me know.

Comment: Ok, if the [1] will show, that approach will not work for me then, I would need for it to not show that and have more precise format including ability to add specific amount of spaces between the Users and Total characters.

Comment: see updated answer. You can manually control the spaces between Users and Total inside the `paste0` function.

Comment: Ok, looks like this can work, I will test it and see how it goes. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work, I first needed to use write.fwf because my text file needed to have fixed widths so I did:

```
write.fwf(data, file = "test.txt", width = c(57,19,2), colnames = FALSE)
```

Then I used:

```
write(paste0("Users:   ", nrow(data),"   Total:    ", sum(data1$amount)), file = "test.txt", append = TRUE)
```

I wanted to post this for reference in case anyone may stumble upon this situation.

Thanks again Shree!